# How does a void type function return a value to a local variable in C without pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, function, return

Here's a program to read an array and print it using functions, in C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void read_arr(int a[10][10],int row,int col)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=row;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=col;j++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter Element %d %d : ",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
void print_arr(int m[10][10],int row,int col)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=row;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=col;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void main()
{
    int m1[10][10],row,col;
    printf("Enter number of rows :\n");
    scanf("%d",&row);
    printf("Enter number of colomns :\n");
    scanf("%d",&col);
    read_arr(m1,row,col);
    printf("\n");
    print_arr(m1,row,col);
}
```

Since we're inputting values into the array 'a' in the function 'read_arr', how are those values being passed into the local variable 'm1' in the 'main' function (we know this because when we pass 'm1' to the function 'print_arr', the output correctly shows the entered array), since we are not returning 'a' from 'read_arr'.

(**Iff** it is possible can you explain how 'm1' is getting values, by explaining how the control goes about in the program)

Comment: Don't forget that array indexes are *zero-based*. I.e. an array of ten elements will have indexes from `0` to `9` (inclusive).

Comment: Note: C 's indexes are zero-based. (`0..9` in your case)

Comment: This is one of the better first questions I've seen. Welcome to SO!

Comment: `m1` is the memory address where the data are stored. You write the data to that memory address. Then you pass the same memory address to another function. The data are there, in that memory, where `m1` is pointing. When you pass `m1` to a function, you don't pass the whole array, you only pass a single value, that is the address of the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments are passed by value in C, but arrays decay to pointers to the first element. So the memory being accessed is the same, which is why the elements are changing.

You can verify this by adding code to print out the value of the array (as a pointer) inside each function, like this in `main()`:

```
printf("the array is at %p\n", (void *) m1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing an array as the argument decayed to pointer in C language. Whenever arrays are passed as the arguments to functions, they are always passed by using the ‘Pass by reference’ mechanism